# Adding a global dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I need a `Dictionary<string, string>` that is available throughout the entire app at runtime. My question is, where is the best place/way to define this `Dictionary`? I assume I need to do it in the Global.asax file. Yet, I'm not sure.

Comment: You can create a helper class to contain it.

Comment: You have to be aware that Dictionary is not thread safe. If you are planning to use it in a "read only" mode it is not a problem, otherwise you should use ConcurrentDictionary<string string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a utility class and use `Lazy` to pospone intialization until the first hit:

```
public static class InfoHelper
{
    private static Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>> infoBuilder
         = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>>( () => SomeCreationMethod() );
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Info
    {
        get
        {
            return infoBuilder.Value;
        }
}
```

Or, using `HttpContext.Cache`:

```
public static class InfoHelper
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Info
    {
        get
        {
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> d
                 = HttpContext.Current.Cache["someId"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;

            if (d == null)
            {
                d = HttpContext.Current.Cache["someId"] = SomeCreationMethod();
            }

            return d;
        }
}
```

Or, when setting this from an external class:

```
public static class InfoHelper
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Info
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Cache["someId"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["someId"] = value;
        }
}
```

Then set it from another class:

```
InfoHelper.Info = ...;
```

Comment: WHere do you call `InfoHelper` though?

Comment: That's up to you. It's static, so just call `InfoHelper.Info`.

Comment: I need to load the dictionary right when the app starts. Yet, I'm not sure where to do that. That is my question.

Comment: Just define a method for `SomeCreationMethod` and you are done.

Comment: Where do you put `SomeCreationMethod`? In the `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method? Or somewhere else?

Comment: I would recommend to keep it in the `InfoHelper` class. Maybe make an initialize method that sets the value. Or a property setter on `Info`.